# .htaccess - Make /some-address the same as /page.php?id=1

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am currently working on a project where I have to redirect a user after a form has been submitted.

Once the form is submitted I redirect the user to a url based on what they entered into the form. An example of what the URL might look like:

/oslo-norway-copenhagen-denmark

I would like /oslo-norway-copenhagen-denmark to display in the users URL bar, would would like it to represent the page /page.php?id=oslo-norway-copenhagen-denmark.

I've currently got this working:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
DirectoryIndex search.php
RewriteBase /services
RewriteRule ^formmail/([^/]*)$ formmail.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

The only problem is that this makes /formmail/oslo-norway-copenhagen-denmark work, but how do I go about making this only /oslo-norway-copenhagen-denmark? I tried removing the /formmail/ but this didn't work

Could anyone help me solve this problem? Thank you very much!

Comment: Show us what you've already tried.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to use is this in your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /services/page.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Make sure you clear your cache before testing it. It will leave you with your desired URL.

Comment: Don't forget to allow direct access to existing files and folders, or it can have some undesired side effects if there are any css/js files in the root folder. So this is not complete.

Comment: Hi, I should probably specify that the website is located on a subdirectory, so domain.com/services/... The script doesn't work on the subdirectory, that is the problem. Do you have a fix for that?

Comment: @thickguru Sorry, that didn't do it I'm afraid